# Simple getJSON does not work

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

JSON function(Index) does not fire.  Any Ideas?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        alert("This alert is displayed :(");
        $("form[action$='GetQuote']").submit(function() {                
            $.getJSON($(this).attr("action"), $(this).serialize(), function(Result) {
                alert("This alert is not shown :(");
                $("#name").html(Result.name);
                $("#address").html(Result.address);
            });   
            return false;
        });
    });    
</script>
```

CONTROLLERS...

```
    public JsonResult GetQuote(string dataName)
    {
        if (dataName != "" || dataName != null)
            return new JsonResult { Data = new Result { name = "Hello", address = "World" } };
        else
            return null;
    }
```

Comment: Does the method `isNullOrEmpty` return a string, or does it return a boolean?

Comment: It returns a string, but I made some changes to accomodate for null or empty.  See Edit

Comment: Use:

`if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(dataName))`

That is an accepted practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ASP.NET MVC 2.0 will throw an error if trying to do this with a HTTP GET by default.  You can either make it a POST or add the instruction as suggested in this article:

http://mhinze.com/json-hijacking-in-asp-net-mvc-2/

which is:
return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you probably should use the `$.ajax` function, and specify a "POST" to post your dataName.

Secondly you probably need to prevent the default event from happening:

```
$("form[action$='GetQuote']").submit(function(event) {
    if (event.preventDefault) // Older I.E. uses an old DOM model, which dosen't have this event
       event.preventDefault();

    $.ajax(...) // Do your ajax call
    return false; // Once again, for I.E.
});
```

The submit event may be overriding your onSubmit bound with jQuery